# I'm writing about advocacy, and I can't find the preposition to use in this specific case;

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions

> I advocate equality ....... decision-makers

I need to fill the space with a preposition that would convey the meaning that I am advocating equality and my target is decision-makers, I don't think it is "to" or "with"

Comment: What about “***for***”? See usage examples here https://www.google.com/search?q=%22advocate%20equality%20for%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2013,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en

Comment: I think that "equality" is the wrong word as it is too vague. With the right word, "in" in the meaning of "as an attribute of" would work, e.g. "Honesty in policemen is to be admired."

Comment: the sentence above is an example to explain where I'm having difficulty, the meaning of the sentence is that I am advocating something, and I need to know what preposition to put before the target of my advocacy, which is the decision-makers

Comment: What do you mean by 'target' here, Ruaa? Those you are advocating on behalf of (needs '_for_') or those you think the people you are advocating on behalf of should have parity with (I'd use '[parity] _with_').

Comment: by "target" I mean the bodies that have the power to change the laws and followed procedures to meet our demands, I mean those who we want, us as groups, and the people we are advocating on behalf, to target with our advocacy campaign. I hope this makes sense and i was able to explain my point. and thank you guys for your help!

Comment: No need to define decision-makers. What you have left unanswered is: Do you want your group to be equal **with** them, or for the decision-makers to treat things **among** themselves equally? Similar to @EdwinAshworth. Who's not getting equality, your group or the decision-makers.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your intended meaning is that you recommend to decision-makers that they use equality, then the appropriate preposition is "to".

"Advocate" functions like its synonym "recommend". "Equality" is the direct object and "decision-makers" the indirect.

Answer (score 0):

> and my target is decision-makers

This can mean at least two different things:

1. You advocate equality *among* decision-makers. That is, you want all the decision-makers to have equal influence on the final decision.
2. You want equality to guide the decision-makers decisions. They should make only decisions which further equality. In this case you advocate equality *to* the decision-makers, as @DJClayworth in his answer said.